# Pass data to UITextField between ViewControllers

Tags: objective-c

I am stuck on passing data from one ViewController to another. The scenario is as:
I have 2 ViewControllers named : SearchDomainController and LoginViewController. What i am trying to do is pass the string value from SearchDomainController to the UITExtfield in LoginViewController.

In LoginViewController i have declared `IBOutlet UITextField *domainField;` and also a property `@property(nonatomic,retain) UITextField *domainField`.

The problem is when i create a new instance of LoginViewController in SearchDomainController and try `_loginViewController.domainField.text = @"Some text";` 
the text never changes in UItextField on LoginViewController. 
What did i miss ? And what are the best solution for this kind of problem? Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that `_loginViewController.domainField` is nil at that time, which is probably because the view hasn't loaded yet, and the label is created when the view loads (via a nib) and not as soon as the view controller object is created.

In order to not depend on having the view fully loaded when passing the value, I would have used a separate property for passing along the title, i.e. `_loginViewController.domainFieldText = @"Some text";`. Then in `viewDidLoad` of the `_loginViewController`, assign the value of `domaonFieldText` to the actual label.

Alternatively, make sure the UILabel instance is created and not nil when you set its text from the other view controller.

Comment: I am considering to use a delegation pattern to solve this problem. Creating a delegate in SearchViewController and pass the value back to LoginViewController. Is it ok to solve it this way ?

Comment: I don't recommend using a delegate here. Delegates are mostly for being notified about internal behaviour in a class you don't control. Not for simply passing along information, which it seems you are doing here.

Answer (score 0):

Set the string as a `property` of the AppDelegate in one view controller, and you can retrieve it from another, and set it as `textField.text`